# Temporarily working remotely in a different state

Tags: united-states, telecommute, taxes, remote-work

Because of Covid the majority of my office has been working remotely since March. They are actually limiting the number of people that can come to the office to 25% of capacity, and you have to get permission to be on the list.

I am considering visiting my parents to help out for a few weeks (my dad has had some recent health problems). I would work remotely from their house. They reside in a different state, and I am curious when this becomes an issue with taxes and regulations. I have gone to visit work locations in different states for a few different companies. Our CEO visits many out of state locations, so I know it is just not physically being in another state that causes a change. So what triggers having to worry about this?

Comment: It seems to me that you are talking about here in the US, but a location in the question or as a tag would clarify.

Comment: While discussing this topic with one of my in-laws (while I was visiting another state & working remotely, no less), he made some mention of his employees only needing to worry if they were working in a different state for more than 50% of the year. Talk to an accountant, or perhaps a lawyer.

Comment: Sorry about not mentioning that I am in the United States. Thanks for adding the tag.

Comment: Does your company have any presence in your parent's state?

Answer (score 1):

The key here is 'visiting', every state has its own requirements but generally speaking, the requirements are based on residency within the state.

If you are indeed visiting for a few weeks I honestly don't think that it will be an issue for you, but to be safe you should check the requirements for the state where your parents live.

Obviously, if you take up residency by changing your mail address, changing your driver's license info, voter registration then taxes do become important.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to check with your Payroll department and they can confirm in regard to tax purposes?

I would speak to my line manager as soon as possible to ensure that he knows you would like to work remotely in order to support your parents short-term.
As your manager, she/he should be open to supporting you in this regard, and ensure your happiness within your role.